# Installing pywin32 for python 3.5 in windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I have experiencing a problem when installing pywin32 for python 3.5 to my windows 7 PC. The problem is, installation wizard stating that I have no any python versioned as 3.5 in my registery.

[image]

My ***pywin32*** file is downloaded from here => [pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.5.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/).

The thing is, when I run `python -V` code line, I am able to see that I've ***python 3.5.2*** on my PC.

[image]

So I don't understand that is the real problem is. Did I get something wrong in logical way?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it could be availabe but not installed. Can you do `where python`? maybe it's a portable edition.

Comment: it shows me this location `D:\Users\orcuny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe` @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: sounds like a wierd install / anaconda or something like that. Can you try reinstalling Python 3.5? It should install in C:\Python35 by default.

Comment: Oh my windows paths are different than regular windows (some kind of company rule). As you see, my ***Users*** are generating under D:\ driver, so my Desktop and other things are in there too. Should I did this in C:\ Driver anyway?

Comment: it seems that python has been installed by just copying it. Changing the location won't have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest you delete everything about python on your computer (do not forget to delete related PATH variables) and install `Anaconda`. You will be able to create several environments and much more.

You can find it in the link below;

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: virtual environments are a part of python. you dont need anaconda for that.. but anaconda is very good as well..

Answer (score 2):

Export in regedit HKLM\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.5-32 and subkeys Replace in an editor "3.5-32" by "3.5" Import the resulting registry file again (by doubleclicking on it).

Answer (score 1):

use "py -m pip install pypiwin32" instead of "py -m pip install pywin32"/"pip install pywin32".

However, I found that pypiwin32 installs version 219. Pywin32's lates version is 221.