# Python library (pywin32) is not loading

Tags: python, pywin32

I am using some functions of windows so I need this library :

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.6.exe/download

My python is 64 bit and 3.6 version. I looked from python.exe.
But when I try to execute the lib on link it asks for 32 version. 
I also downloaded 32 bit version it loaded but this time IDE gives me library can't found error :

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Edit: The library program says :

> Python version 3.6 32 bit required, which is not found in registry

Also here is the link for the other dude who had the same problem:
https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/731/

Edit 3: I also tried to add `-32` to name version numbers at registry. This time it didn't give any error when I try to load pywin32, and it's loaded. But now I am getting this error :

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Last edit :

Well I am writing this if someone else lives the same things, just delete phyton and install 3.5 version. It works well..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614608/installing-pywin32-for-python-3-5-in-windows-7